# Show console.log in ConEmu

Tags: console, conemu

ConEmu does not display `console.log('variable')`:
[image]

It only shows when highlighted:
[image]

**How do setting it so that it is displayed?**

Comment: Ask grunt authors why they print black text on black background.

Comment: Thanks @Maximus. I used [Console2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) or Git Bash, it was OK.